# Hangfire EnqueuedJobs parameters

Tags: hangfire

I am trying to retrieve the enqueued jobs in Hangfire, using the following code:

```
IMonitoringApi monitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

var jobData = monitor.EnqueuedJobs(?, 0, 1);
```

The [api](http://api.hangfire.io/html/M_Hangfire_Storage_IMonitoringApi_EnqueuedJobs.htm) says the first parameter is a string, (string queue). My question is, what does that string queue indicate and how do I get that? Thanks

Comment: "enqueued jobs", do you mean job with Enqueued status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the name of the Queue where you have put the job as you can make as many as queue in the Hangfire.

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    Queues = new[] { "critical", "default" }
};

app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

Here there are two queues one is critical and second one is default

so here you will pass default if you have not created any queues as default queue is the one which is default queue.

Implement the function as

```
public JobList<EnqueuedJobDto> EnqueuedJobs(string queue, int @from, int perPage)
        {
            return UseConnection(connection =>
            {
                var queueApi = GetQueueApi(connection, queue);
                var enqueuedJobIds = queueApi.GetEnqueuedJobIds(queue, from, perPage);

                return EnqueuedJobs(connection, enqueuedJobIds);
            });
        }
```

Link for implementation here https://searchcode.com/codesearch/raw/97584324/

Let me know if you accomplish it.

Comment: Cool can you share how you ended up it, like implementation of interface, snippet of your interface like getting list of server etc.That will be much appreciated

Comment: Well, I simply used the string`default`. When I had originally asked the question, I was not aware that Hangfire queues have a name. I ended up with this: `var jobData = monitor.EnqueuedJobs('default', 0, 1);`

Comment: So you must be trying to make your own dashboard and the first line of the code in question must be giving you all the methods and thus in jobData you would be getting related data that mean the above two line will provide you data according to method, Thanks